# Azure ML: sweep job completes but status doesn't change from "Running"

Tags: python, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service, ml-studio

Using azureml Python SDK from my local machine, I am able to configure a Hyperdrive sweep job and submit to a compute cluster in Azure Machine Learning Studio. Here is a sample of my code, based on [this tutorial from Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-tune-hyperparameters):

```
#import required libraries
from azure.ai.ml import MLClient, command
from azure.ai.ml.sweep import Choice
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
# from azure.ai.ml.entities import Environment
#connect to the workspace
ml_client = MLClient.from_config(DefaultAzureCredential())

def build_sweep_job(experiment_name, jobname):
    # Create your base command job
    env = '...'
    compute = '...'
    params = [1, 2]
    n_jobs = len(models)
    max_trials = n_jobs
    cmd = 'python train.py --param ${{inputs.params}}'
    inputs = {
        'params': params[0],
    }
    command_job = command(code='codepath', command=cmd, environment=env, inputs=inputs, compute=compute, experiment_name=experiment_name)
    # Override your inputs with parameter expressions
    command_job_for_sweep = command_job(models=Choice(values=models))
    sweep_job = command_job_for_sweep.sweep(
        compute=compute,
        sampling_algorithm='grid',
        primary_metric='Best value',
        goal='Minimize',
    )
    # Specify your experiment details
    sweep_job.display_name = jobname
    sweep_job.experiment_name = experiment_name
    sweep_job.description = 'Run a hyperparameter sweep job.'
    sweep_job.set_limits(max_concurrent_trials=n_jobs, max_total_trials=max_trials)
    sweep_job.early_termination = None
    
    return sweep_job


sweep_job = build_sweep_job(experiment_name='my_experiment', jobname='todays_job')
returned_sweep_job = ml_client.create_or_update(sweep_job)
print(returned_sweep_job.services["Studio"].endpoint)
```

The code correctly creates and runs my job as intended. In the end, ML Studio web interface shows it as completed:

[image]

However, in my Python Notebook running in VS Code, status is shown as "Running" even like one hour after completion:

[image]

How can I solve it? I would like to know, without leaving my local VS Code, that my job has succesfully ended.

Comment: Please describe your steps and expectations in detail.  Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

[minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the provide information, it seems there is a delay with `returned_job.status`.

One possible solution to get the correct status of your job, you can use `ml_client.jobs.list()` to get the updated details for your jobs.

Below is sample code snippet (Modify according to your requirement):

```py
for run in ml_client.jobs.list():
      if run.experiment_name == "<Experiment Name>": 
              print("Name",run.display_name)
              print("Type",run.type)
              print("Compute",run.compute)
              print("Status",run.status)
```

With above code snippet I'm able to get updated status.
[image]